# Demote the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges to bronze and silver respectively

Tags: feature-request, badges, activity-badges

EDIT: As an alternative solution to my original, widely unaccepted question -

Demote the Enthusiast badge to bronze, and the Fanatic badge to silver, as they don't require the same kind of effort other badges in their respective categories do.

Comment: If you're dedicated enough to want to write up a script, why not? It's not like it's one of the content-related badges.

Comment: there is "protection" in place, it's just not documented, for hopefully obvious reasons

Comment: Three *different* actions? Like I can't answer three questions and sign off? Is rep counted even if some action earns it on a different day? Way too complicated for a feature (badges) that's supposed to be fun (this one in particular).

Comment: Yes, I suspect that said "protection" is what's kept me from getting Fanatic on the other three, despite the fact that I know I personally did visit them (even if just to load up their home pages) for well over 100 days straight ... :) I've given up "trying" to get them; I'll just get them when the time is right. (Which is probably the intent anyway.)

Comment: Check out revision 1 of this question for all of the flame inducing goodness :)

Answer (score 10):

If you've gone to the trouble of writing a script to log you in today, isn't that somewhat fanatical behaviour to start with?

Your rules would just make the script slightly harder to write: add a comment, wait, delete it, repeat... job done.

Comment: That is... until you hit a CAPTCHA :)

Comment: *Meh*, I hit those captchas too often, don't remind me.

Comment: Ad writing the script just to get the badges - user [Dori](http://stackexchange.com/users/6489/dori?tab=accounts) seems to be such an example. She has Fanatic badges on *tens* of sites without barely any other activity.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that Fanatic does not satisfy the criteria to be a gold badge, I'm opposed to doing things like that to make achieving it marginally more difficult. It sounds like security-by-obscurity. It will not have a significant benefit but increases complexity and will use the development resources of Jeff & Co. that can be used to make the system better. **Features don't come free**.

Comment: I agree they don't come free, but then again, I won't be implementing said features.